# How to change json response to string using ruby code

Tags: ruby

i am new with ruby code, so i have this response :

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "name":"Andy",
         "user_type":0,
         "info":"",
         "user_info":null,
         "new":false,
         "active":false,
         "cities":[

         ],
         "visibility_settings":{
            "general":false,
            "product":false
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

how to change it to_string in ruby code, like this

```
"name":"Andy",
"user_type":"0",
"info":"",
"user_info":"null",
"new":"false",
"active":"false",
"cities":"[]",
"visibility_settings":{
"general":"false",
"product":"false"
}
```

because i want to compare it with my datatable :

```
| name    | user_type | new   | user_info |
| Andy    | 1         | false | true      |
```

and my script is like this :

```
And("response "jsonpath" filter "filter" have:") do |jpath, filter, table|
      response = JsonPath.new("#{jpath}").on(@response).to_a.first
      table = table.hashes
      table.each do |data|
        target = response.select { |resp| resp["#{filter}"] == data["#{filter}"] }   data.each { |key, value| expect(data).to eq(target.first) }
      end
    end
```

Comment: You don't need to "change" it, just access to the object in the `data` key (`JSON.parse(response['data'][0])`).

Comment: Why on earth would you need to cast into a string to compare it with DB values? This sounds like a self-inflicted problem caused by a bad schema.

Comment: this is for my step definition of my automation test. so i want to make all response.body as string first then compare it with expected value